# How do I get the Firebase URL in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

```
    var reference = Firebase(url: "https://myapp.firebaseio.com/the_awesome_node")
    reference.observeEventType(FEventType.Value, withBlock: {  (snapshot) -> Void in
        //do something
    })
```

Later on in my code, I want to get `https://myapp.firebaseio.com/the_awesome_node` given the reference (of class Firebase).

I couldn't find it in the API.

Answer (score 1):

Solved:

```
reference.parent + "/" + reference.key
```

Comment: Alternatively `reference.parent.childByAppendingPath(reference.key)`. See https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/saving-data.html#section-setvalue